# python libtorrent fast resume

Tags: python, libtorrent

I attempted to write a simple bittorrent client using the `libtorrent` python binding.

I used the `save_status()` and `load_status()` to store and retrieve session settings. But it doesn't seem to work. The session settings didn't include my previous download information. Then I use the `torrent_handle.save_resume_data()`. This function just returns `None` type.
I believe this function is the one to use. But I didn't know how to specify the location and name of the resume file.

Is there any documentation of saving the current download torrent information, so that I can resume torrent downloading? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

saving and loading the session state does not include the torrent files. It just includes settings and DHT state. You still need to re-add the torrents.

As for examples, here's one that saves resume data and .torrent files in a sqlite3 database (which is quite efficient).

https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent-webui/blob/master/src/save_resume.cpp
https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent-webui/blob/master/src/save_resume.hpp

(it needs to subscribe to alerts, to keep resume data up-to-date. For this it fits into a alert subscription framework which is also part of that repository)